# Is there conditional sourcing in R/RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to conditionally run 3 different modules in one R script. Right now, I am using if(0) on each of them. e.g. I am loading a graph, and then running module B using following code. It is painful to use if() loops for every module (scrolling), is there way I can do conditional sourcing of R script in RStudio (like MACROS in C)?

```
load_graph()

if(0){
module A
.....
}

#if(0){
module B
....
}

if(0){
module C
....
}
```

Comment: I could not understand why an edit was required? Could you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign a variable to indicate which you would like to run

```
whichmodule='b'
load_graph()

if(whichmodule=='a'){
module A
.....
}

if(whichmodule=='b'){
module B
....
}

if(whichmodule=='c'){
module C
....
}
```

with this structure you can set the module in the first bit then source the whole document and only get the b module to run.